# hide the title attribute tooltip on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have `<a></a>` with title attribute.on hover the link it shows default tooltip.I want to hide the tooltip on hover the anchor tag. on mouseout I need to add title attribute again. now onhover remove title attribute and doesn't append title on mouseout event

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("title");
      },
      function() {
        $(this).attr("title");
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=# title="sample">Hover Here</a>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen with `$( this ).attr( "title" )`?

Comment: on hover it shows sample.

Comment: What are you trying to do that can not be achieved much easier by not having a title attribute at all? The only function of the title attribute is to show info on hover, so what do you need it for, if not for hovering purposes?

Answer (score 1):

This might be, what you are looking for

This will "remove" the `title` and save the value into an attribute that is called `save_title`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").mouseenter(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("title");
      $(this).attr("save_title", title);
      $(this).attr("title", "");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("save_title");
      $(this).attr("title", title);
    })
    .click(function() {
      var title = $(this).attr("save_title");
      $(this).attr("title", title);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=# title="sample">Hover Here</a>
```

Comment: @user3386779 happy to help

Comment: Would a `data` attribute not be more semantically correct here? E.g. `data-title`?

Comment: @fubar For som maybe, but for the example it don't change much

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, granted it doesn't change the example, but are underscores in attribute names not against the HTML spec? And that's what the `data` attributes were meant for.